# Unable to show the data in table according to the value entered in serach field

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

```
 <input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Seach For Data..." title="Type in a name">  
 <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
    <thead class="cf">
    <tr id="headingTR" style="display:yes">
    <th style="text-align:center">Application No.</th>
    <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
    <th style="width:15%;text-align:center" class="numeric">Name</th>
    <th style="width:5%;text-align:center" class="numeric">Moblile No.</th>
    <th style="width:45%;text-align:center" class="numeric">Detail</th>
    <th style="width:10%;text-align:center" class="numeric">Tag</th>
    <th style="width:5%;text-align:center" class="numeric">Status</th>
    <th style="width:10%;text-align:center" >Download</th>
    <th style="width:15%;text-align:center" class="numeric">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="noRecordTR" style="display:none"> 
    <td>No Data</td>                              
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
    <?php 
                include("pagination/function1.php");
    $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
    $limit = 5; //if you want to dispaly 10 records per page then you have to change here
    $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
    $sql_block = "SELECT * FROM citizen_request ORDER BY sno DESC LIMIT $startpoint, $limit";
    $block_data = mysqli_query($con,$sql_block);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($block_data) ){
                    $id = $row['sno'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $mobile = $row['mobile'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $remark = $row['remark'];
                    $uniqueid = $row['id'];
                    $status = $row['status'];
                    $file = $row['file'];
                    if ($file=="")
                    {
                        $file="blank.php";
                    }
                    ?> 
    <tr>
    <td data-title="Application No"><?=$uniqueid?></td>
    <td data-title="ID" style="display:none;"><?=$id?></td>
    <td class="numeric" data-title="Name"><?=$name?></td>
    <td class="numeric" data-title="Mobile"><?=$mobile?></td>
    <td class="numeric" data-title="Detail"><?=$description?></td>
    <td class="numeric" data-title="Tag"><?=$remark?></td>
    <td class="numeric"  data-title="Status"> <span class="badge badge-primary"><?=$status?> </span></td>
    <td class="numeric"  data-title="Download"><a class=" btn btn-success btn-sm" href="upload/request/<?=$file?>" target=_blank> Download</a></td>
    <td class="numeric"  data-title="Action">
    <a href="edit-request.php?sno=<?=$id?>" onclick="return confirmation()" ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>
    <a href="delete_request.php?sno=<?=$id?>" onclick="return confirmation()"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
     $sno=$sno+1;
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my table search field.
And this my script for getting the data searched by the user.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
       var flag = false;
       var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'getRequestSearch.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {value:value},
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success:function(response){

                        var len = response.length;
                        if(len == 0){

                        } else{
                          var data = "";
                          var sno = 1;
                            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                                var id = response[i]['id'];
                                var name = response[i]['name'];
                                var mobile = response[i]['mobile']; 
                                var description = response[i]['description']; 

                                var remark = response[i]['remark'];
                                var app_no = response[i]['app_no'];
                                var status = response[i]['status'];
                                var file = response[i]['file'];
                                if(file==""||file=="no")
                                {
                                    file="blank";
                                }else
                                {

                                }

                                    if(id=="")
                                    {

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        data += '<tr><td data-title="Application No.">' + app_no + '</td><td data-title="ID" style="display:none;">' + id + '</td> <td class="numeric" data-title="Name">' + name + '</td><td class="numeric" data-title="Mobile">'+ mobile + '</td><td class="numeric" data-title="Description">'+ description +'</td><td class="numeric" data-title="Remark">' +remark+ '</td><td class="numeric"  data-title="Status"><span class="badge badge-primary">'+ status +'</span></td> <td class="numeric"  data-title="Download"><a class=" btn btn-success btn-sm" href="upload/request/'+file+'" target=_blank>Download</a></td><td class="numeric"  data-title="Operation"><a href="edit-request.php?sno='+id+'" onclick="return confirmation()" ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a><a href="delete_request.php?sno='+id+'" onclick="return confirmation()"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button></a></td></tr>';  
                                    }
                                    sno++;
                    $("#download-excel").attr("href", "excel-request.php?status="+status_sel+"");
                                    $("#download-excel").attr("target","_blank");
                                    $("#download-zip").attr("href", "download-zip-request.php?status="+status_sel+"");
                                    $("#download-zip").attr("target","_blank");


                            }
                            $("#data").html(data)
                        }



                    }


                });
            });
      });
```

As i Enter name it is getting the data in response according to what i type in the search field.. but table data isnt changing.
And also m using WHERE name LIKE %$value%; but how can i search for multiple columns or all column.

Comment: What have you done so far, to try and debug the problem? Does the browser console show any errors? Did you try to step through your JS code in the debugger?

Comment: _“And also m using WHERE name LIKE %$value%; but how can i search for multiple columns or all column.”_ - by adding additional conditions for each column. (If that is not what you want, then maybe look into _fulltext search_.)

Comment: you have `onkeyup="myFunction()"` as well as `$("#myInput").on("keyup", function()` for same element why ?

Comment: no there is no error... and also m getting my proper json array. @CBroe

Comment: like if i type "luf" in search field this is my response ``[{"id":"4","name":"Luffy","mobile":"8xxxx960","description":"Decription Is As Follows","remark":"forwarded to PM","app_no":"20200516141728","status":"\u0928\u093f\u0935\u0947\u0926\u0928 \u091c\u092e\u093e","file":""},{"id":"9","name":"Luffy","mobile":"81xxxx0","description":"Decription Is As Follows","remark":"forwarded to PM","app_no":"20200516141728","status":"\u0928\u093f\u0935\u0947\u0926\u0928 \u091c\u092e\u093e","file":""}]``

Comment: @Swat that myfunction was something that i tried but didnt work.. so i have removed the function already... removing it doesnt change anything

Comment: so the problem is in displaying data ? response is also correct ?

Comment: yes...@Swati m unable to display it.. since nothing is changing in my table.. but m getting proper response as mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
       var flag = false;
       var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'getRequestSearch.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {value:value},
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success:function(response){

                        var len = response.length;
                        if(len == 0){

                        } else{
                          var data = "";
                          var sno = 1;
                            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                                var id = response[i]['id'];
                                var name = response[i]['name'];
                                var mobile = response[i]['mobile']; 
                                var description = response[i]['description']; 

                                var remark = response[i]['remark'];
                                var app_no = response[i]['app_no'];
                                var status = response[i]['status'];
                                var file = response[i]['file'];
                                if(file==""||file=="no")
                                {
                                    file="blank";
                                }else
                                {

                                }

                                    if(id=="")
                                    {

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        data += '<tr><td data-title="Application No.">' + app_no + '</td><td data-title="ID" style="display:none;">' + id + '</td> <td class="numeric" data-title="Name">' + name + '</td><td class="numeric" data-title="Mobile">'+ mobile + '</td><td class="numeric" data-title="Description">'+ description +'</td><td class="numeric" data-title="Remark">' +remark+ '</td><td class="numeric"  data-title="Status"><span class="badge badge-primary">'+ status +'</span></td> <td class="numeric"  data-title="Download"><a class=" btn btn-success btn-sm" href="upload/request/'+file+'" target=_blank>Download</a></td><td class="numeric"  data-title="Operation"><a href="edit-request.php?sno='+id+'" onclick="return confirmation()" ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a><a href="delete_request.php?sno='+id+'" onclick="return confirmation()"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button></a></td></tr>';  
                                    }
                                    sno++;
                    $("#download-excel").attr("href", "excel-request.php?status="+status"");
                                    $("#download-excel").attr("target","_blank");
                                    $("#download-zip").attr("href", "download-zip-request.php?status="+status"");
                                    $("#download-zip").attr("target","_blank");


                            }
                            $("#data").html(data)
                        }



                    }


                });
            });
      });
```

Only thing i see is status_sel not defined.. now it should work

Comment: how that should work ? what changes you made in above code add that as well ?

Comment: i mentioned it @Swati all i changed is status_sel to status since var status_sel was not defined

Comment: yes it worked for me.. status_sel was from defined in other funtion and because it i guess it was not working.